# JSFL typewriter effects for Flash CS6

Tags: flash, flash-cs6, jsfl

Hopefully this is a quick one - I haven't touched flash since cs3 and the following jsfl typewriter effect use to work. I'm not sure if there is a bug but in CS6 the effect actually works backwards - as if it has reversed the selection? The last letters animate in first instead of the first animating in.

Does anyone know of a solution? JSFL below

---

```
var doc = fl.getDocumentDOM();

doc.breakApart();
doc.distributeToLayers();
doc.selectAll();


var obs = doc.selection;
doc.getTimeline().insertFrames( obs.length * 2, true, 1); 

var tl = doc.getTimeline();
var total = obs.length;
var i = total + 1;


while( i-- ){
    tl.setSelectedLayers( i, true );
    tl.cutFrames(0);
    tl.pasteFrames( i * 2 );
    tl.clearFrames(0, (i * 2));

}
```

Comment: +1 to anyone who has to deal with that ***\*\*\*message redacted\*\*\**** language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the order in which distribute to layers works has reversed at some point. In any case, simply inverting the layer selection works for me:

```
tl.setSelectedLayers( total - i, true );
```

Comment: Maybe I've just had an off day but I swear I tried that. Thanks heaps.